# ERROR ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis IN CREATE TABLE ARTICLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is the query I use, but I get an error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE Article
(
    ArCode CHAR(5) LIKE 'A%' PRIMARY KEY,
    ArName VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    Rate NUMBER(8,2),
    Quantity NUMBER(4) DEFAULT 0 CHECK(Quantity >= 0),
    Class CHAR(1) LIKE '[A-C]'
)
```

Comment: Please mark what you RDB version

Answer (score 1):

There are more problems in your code. I think the following statement is what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE Article
(
    ArCode   CHAR(5) check (arcode LIKE 'A%') PRIMARY KEY,
    ArName   VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    Rate     NUMBER(8, 2),
    Quantity NUMBER(4) DEFAULT 0 CHECK(Quantity >= 0),
    Class    CHAR(1) check (class in ('A', 'B', 'C'))
);
```

You should also correct the check constraint of the Class column. A better solution is creating a table for your class values and instead of the check constraint you can use a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Please use some tool that automatically highlights the issue.

In your example, the Issue is missing the `CHECK` keyword for your check constraint.

Use following:

```
CREATE TABLE article
( arcode CHAR(5) check (arcode LIKE 'A%') PRIMARY KEY, -- change in this line
ArName VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL, 
Rate NUMBER(8,2), 
Quantity NUMBER(4) DEFAULT 0 CHECK(Quantity >= 0),  -- change in this line
class char(1) check (class LIKE '[A-C]'));
```